# DRY up similar form classes

Tags: python, django

I have an python/django application with simple captcha.
Simple captcha is appeared according to some algorithm.

There are two almost same constructors. The difference is just in inheritance.
How to avoid code duplication?

```
class PostCaptchaForm(PostForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs['request']
        del kwargs['request']

        super(PostCaptchaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PostCaptchaForm, self).clean()

        success = self.is_valid()
        utils.update_captcha_access(self.request, success)

        if success:
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("captcha validation failed")


class ThreadCaptchaForm(ThreadForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')

        super(ThreadCaptchaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ThreadCaptchaForm, self).clean()

        success = self.is_valid()
        utils.update_captcha_access(self.request, success)

        if success:
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("captcha validation failed")
```

Comment: This is fine, I would'nt worry about changing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with multiple inheritance, with a base captcha form as a mixin, to be used alongside ThreadForm or PostForm

```
class CaptchaFormBase(forms.Form):  # or forms.ModelForm, if appropriate

    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')  
        # this is the same as assigning to self request then deleting the key

        super(CaptchaFormBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CaptchaFormBase, self).clean()

        success = self.is_valid()
        utils.update_captcha_access(self.request, success)

        if not success:
            # this will put things in non_field_errors, you may want to put it in self.errors['captcha']
            raise forms.ValidationError("Captcha validation failed")

        # always make it easy to see that you're returning cleaned_data
        return self.cleaned_data


class PostCaptchaForm(PostForm, CaptchaFormBase):
    pass


class ThreadCaptchaForm(ThreadForm, CaptchaFormBase):
    pass
```